# What is the difference between CMAKE_INSTALL_PRFEIX and DESTDIR ? Where to use when?

Tags: installation, cmake, makefile

What is the difference between CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and DESTDIR ? Where to use when ?

From [cmake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/DESTDIR.html) its not very clear as to which should be used ?

Can I set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to one path and set DESTDIR to another different path compared to the one supplied to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX (not that I want to, but what does doing this imply)?

Concept clarification. Did not try anything.

Comment: "_`make DESTDIR=/package/stage install`
will install the software using the installation prefix, e.g. /usr/local, prepended with the DESTDIR value which gives /package/stage/usr/local. The packaging tool may then construct the package from the content of the /package/stage directory._"

Comment: "_\[`DESTDIR`\] It is commonly used by packagers to install software in a staging directory._"

Comment: what is the purpose of a staging directory during the process of creating packages ?

Comment: that's another question

Answer (score 2):

`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is specific to `cmake`, and has well-defined semantics within `cmake` itself.

`DESTDIR` is a convention for `make` (and other similar tools) which specifies the root directory where something should be installed on a system.

One common example is related to packaging your software. Out of the box, if compiled locally, it would install into `/usr/local`; but a package manager, while building the package (`.deb` or `.rpm` or etc) will want to "install" into a temporary build directory, and within that into `usr` instead of `usr/local`.

See also [`DESTDIR` in the GNU Coding Standard.](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html)

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` specifies where the software should be installed - so it controls `rpath` for shared libraries.

`DESTDIR` is used to *temporarily* install the software somewhere else - but without changing `rpath` and other paths - typically for binary packaging purposes.

You could for instance set `DESTDIR` to some temporary directory to create a binary package - that's intended to be installed into `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`.

Comment: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` specifies the ***default*** install location that's used for the installation target created by cmake (the logic invoked by `make install` for the "Unix Makefile" CMake generator). This installation should update the rpath, regardless of whether `DESTDIR` is used or not, but not 100% sure, if the resulting rpaths will be the ones for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` or for `DESTDIR`. You can still overwrite this via `--prefix` option, e.g. `cmake --install build_dir --prefix install_dir`; this will adjust rpaths.