# What is the purpose of a staging directory while package installation and creation?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, yocto, packaging, deb

What is the purpose of a staging directory while package installation and creation ? What is the application of the staging directory when cross compiling and in non cross compiling situations?

This question is in relation to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76233951/what-is-the-difference-between-cmake-install-prfeix-and-destdir-where-to-use-w).

Comment: Please read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post. Do not ask for opinions. Post an [on-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) problem with details that can be answered with facts and/or citations.

Answer (score 1):

There are many situations in which packaging involves more than just creating an archive of all of the files. For example, when creating an .dmg for MacOS you need to sign all binaries within the app bundle before creating the installer. One way to do that is to first install everything to the staging area, then iterate through all of the binaries installed there and sign them, and then finally creating the .dmg.

You could of course also sign everything during the respective installation step instead of as part of the packaging step, but then every developer on the team would need a valid Apple Code Signing certificate to run the `install` target locally. This is undesirable, in particular for open-source projects where ideally only the maintainer of the project will create releases, so only they should need to sign stuff.

Another example is the creation of Debian packages. Debian packages contain a file with the md5 hashes of all files that are part of the package. So the Debian package generator installs everything to the staging area, then creates the hashes for all of the files, afterwards adds additional files for control data (e.g. dependencies of the package) before finally creating the .deb file from everything now located in the staging area.

Comment: Good answer, but maybe some things that `cmake --install build_dir --prefix ...` (which is effectively used by cpack) does should be added: 1. The files can be modified (e.g. updating of the rpath 2. new files may be generated (`install(EXPORT)`, `install(CODE)` in some cases, ...)

Comment: @fabian can you elaborate on your comment please.

Comment: @AkashR I just mentioned a few things that may be worth noting. An comment is insufficient to add a in depth expanation and I won't write an answer. Here are a few pointers to cmake doc you could use as start for research, if you're interested though. rpath: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH.html install (relevant "signatures" `SCRIPT`, `CODE`, `EXPORT`): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html